# React hooks useState doesnt update correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mobx

I have a weird issue with react + mobx + hooks API not updating state correctly

This is a console output of the example below. Nevermind about findDomNode error, it's related to toast component library being out of date

[image]

Let's say there is a list of services and an array of corresponding ids. It's an admin panel where I want to add or delete current services on the server-side. I store selected services (i.e. checkboxes) in `useState`. It's also possible to remove service from the backend and therefore I need to update the selected (checkboxed) list on the frontend with what comes in a backend response

The problem is that hook showing that update is right inside `useEffect`, but inside render function (`handleListColCallback`) `selected` values is not updating, always keeping deleted values

Have tried multiple combinations of `useMemo`, `useCallback`, etc. There result is always the same. Am I doing something wrong?

```js
const AdminServices = observer(() => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  const serviceContext = useContext(ServiceStoreContext);

  const handleListColCallback = async (params) => {
    if (params.type === 'select-checkbox') {
      // STEP 3 - I want to manipulate with state removing or adding checked id to array 
      // ERROR here - selected state still showing old value (not the same as in useEffect)
      console.log('checkbox select', selected);

    } else if (params.type === 'delete-from-node') {
      // STEP 1 - I call delete action, it runs successfully
      await serviceContext
        .deleteFromNode({ service_id: params.id })
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // STEP 2 - when mobx store updates, I want to reset component state with new values
    setSelected(serviceContext.nodeListArrayIds);
  }, [serviceContext.nodeListArrayIds]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // selected shows current values (this effect is just for testing)
    console.log('selected updated', selected);
  }, [selected]);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Issue solved by using following setState and `handleListColCallback` update. Would be happy if somebody could explain the difference why pure `setState` is that different vs `setState((curState) => ... )`

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setSelected(() => {
      return [...serviceContext.nodeListArrayIds];
    });
  }, [serviceContext.nodeListArrayIds]);
```

```js
    } else if (params.type === 'select-checkbox') {
      setSelected((selected) => {
        const index = selected.indexOf(params.id);

        if (index === -1) {
          return [...selected, ...[params.id]];
        } else {
          return selected.filter((x) => x !== params.id);
        }
      });
```

Comment: Maybe that is because first runs console.log('checkbox select', selected) and only then deleteFromNode runs? try running that function again and see if on second run what you deleted previously is deleted.

Comment: Can 39 get re-added back to `nodeListArrayIds` somehow? Try with `setSelected([...serviceContext.nodeListArrayIds]);`

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Right direction, issue is solved, but honestly I'm not quite understating why. Added example of working code in the update. Feel free to post answer, will mark as solved

Comment: Always thought destructuring is relevant to objects because it's just a reference. Isn't array in constant creates new instance ?

Comment: 'setState` does not create a new object, it just saves the same reference to a new variable. I'd look into why 39 re-appears in the context, doesn't look right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the array in the context (`serviceContext.nodeListArrayIds`) somehow gets the deleted item re-added (something the OP might want to investigate).

The difference between `setSelected(serviceContext.nodeListArrayIds);` and `setSelected([...serviceContext.nodeListArrayIds]);` is that in the first case `selected` is a reference to `serviceContext.nodeListArrayIds` and thus will reflect any changes to it. `[...serviceContext.nodeListArrayIds]` creates a shallow clone (similar to `.slice()`), so changes to `serviceContext.nodeListArrayIds` do not affect it.